# How to read whole file path within upload files

Tags: javascript, html

How to read full path on uploaded files?

I tried to drag and drop many folders to upload at a time.

However, I could only see the filename from FileList object.

How could I get the file path in this case?

If read file paths is not allowed, can we allow users to upload a **.zip** file which contains multi-level folders and unzip it on the frontend. Can we get the file_path information by doing so?

[image]

Comment: For obvious security reasons...you can't

Comment: You cannot get access to full paths in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you can't get any information from the user system.

That would be a potential security and privacy breach. Plus there's no reasons for you to need it.

Comment: Is there any SPEC defined for this topic?

Comment: You can find more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security). At some point [this API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) was added to some browsers, but I'm not sure if it's still available and probably very limited if it is.

Comment: Thanks for this correct info